# Angular Firestore: Map DocumentReference attribute to object while fetching collection

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

I have an entity:

```
export interface FriendRequest {
    sender: Profile;
    recipient: Profile;
    isAccepted: boolean;
    dateSend: Date;
    dateAccepted?: Date;
}
```

This is how these etities are saved in firestore:

[image: This is how these etities are saved in firestore]

**The problem:**
I want to fetch all documents from `friend-request` collection and map `recipient`, `sender` from `DocumentReference` type to `Profile` object.

I tried this. This is my method which fetches all `friend-request` documents:

```js
listenOnReceivedFriendRequests(profileId: string): Observable<Array<FriendRequest>> {
        const myProfileReference = this.$db.doc(`${PROFILE_COLLECTION}/${profileId}`);

        return this.$db.collection<FriendRequest>(
            FRIEND_REQUEST_COLLECTION,
            ref => ref.where('recipient', '==', myProfileReference.ref)
        )
            .valueChanges()
            .pipe(
                map((friendRequests) => {
                    return friendRequests.map((friendRequest) => {

                        // This is the place where it goes wrong I guess
                        return {
                            ...friendRequest,
                            sender: friendRequest.sender.get().then((senderDoc) => friendRequest.sender = senderDoc.data()),
                            recipient: friendRequest.recipient.get().then((senderDoc) => friendRequest.recipient = senderDoc.data())
                        };
                    });

                }),
                tap(result => console.log(result))
            );
    }
```

But it returns:

```js
[
    {
        sender: ZoneAwarePromise,       // <-- Instead of Profile object
        recipient: ZoneAwarePromise,    // <-- Instead of Profile object
        isAccepted: ...,
        dateSend: ...,
        dateAccepted: ...,
    },
    {
        sender: ZoneAwarePromise,       // <-- Instead of Profile object
        recipient: ZoneAwarePromise,    // <-- Instead of Profile object
        isAccepted: ...,
        dateSend: ...,
        dateAccepted: ...,
    },
]
```

Instead of my **required output**:

```js
[
    {
        sender: Profile,
        recipient: Profile,
        isAccepted: ...,
        dateSend: ...,
        dateAccepted: ...,
    },
    {
        sender: Profile,
        recipient: Profile,
        isAccepted: ...,
        dateSend: ...,
        dateAccepted: ...,
    },
]
```

I know I should wait until promises of `sender` and `recipient` finish, but I dont know how to do it to return my required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `map` operator, you can handle it like the following:

- Use one of the [higher-order RxJS mapping operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/), to map each one of the `FriendRequest` to an `Observable`.
- Each `Observable` will fetch the related `sender` and `recipient` by combining the two `Promise`(s) to one `Observable` using [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) function (after converting each one of the `Promise`(s) to an `Observable` using [from](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) function)
- Then map each `Observable` result again to a `FriendRequest` object.
- Wrap the result array of `Observable` with `forkJoin` function, to return in the end `Array<FriendRequest`.

Try something like the following:

```js
// import { forkJoin, from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
// import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

listenOnReceivedFriendRequests(
  profileId: string
): Observable<Array<FriendRequest>> {
  const myProfileReference = this.$db.doc(
    `${PROFILE_COLLECTION}/${profileId}`
  );

  return this.$db
    .collection<FriendRequest>(FRIEND_REQUEST_COLLECTION, (ref) =>
      ref.where('recipient', '==', myProfileReference.ref)
    )
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((friendRequests: Array<FriendRequest>) =>
        // forkJoin returns Observable<Array<FriendRequest>>
        forkJoin(
          // map each item to an Observable<FriendRequest>, after resolving the related profiles.
          friendRequests.map((friendRequest) =>
            forkJoin({
              senderDoc: from(friendRequest.sender.get()),
              recipientDoc: from(friendRequest.recipient.get()),
            }).pipe(
              map(({ senderDoc, recipientDoc }) => ({
                ...friendRequest,
                sender: senderDoc.data(),
                recipient: recipientDoc.data(),
              }))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is returning `Observable<Observable<FriendRequest>>` instead of `Observable<Array<FriendRequest>>`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I just forgot to wrap the result array with `forkJoin`. I updated my answer, please check it now.